# How to compress a YAML file using references in a script?

Tags: javascript, yaml

I am converting a json file to a YAML file with https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml using safeDump

The outcome is like this

```
en:
  models: 
    errors:
      name: name not found
      url: bad url
  user: 
    errors:
      name: name not found
      url: bad url
  photo:
    errors:
      name: name not found
      url: bad url
```

but I want a script to compress with the references

```
en:
  models: 
    errors: &1
      name: name not found
      url: bad url
  user:
    errors: *1
  photo:
    errors: *1
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/486
Seems like I will still have to mark my duplicates myself, but at least it is something. 
Is there a way to mark duplicates before from the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is "compressing" the JSON input to YAML with references for those mappings that
have exactly the same key-value pairs. In order to achieve that you need to be able to find
such matching mappings and one way to do that is by creating a lookup table based on
the string representation of the mapping *after sorting the keys*.

Assuming this JSON input in `input.json`:

```
{
  "en": {
    "models": {
      "errors": {
        "name": "name not found",
        "url": "bad url"
      }
    },
    "user": {
      "errors": {
        "name": "name not found",
        "url": "bad url"
      }
    },
    "photo": {
      "errors": {
        "name": "name not found",
        "url": "bad url"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can convert it with this Python script to get:

```
import json
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.json')


def optmap(d, mappings=None):
    if mappings is None:
        mappings = {}
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            v = d[k]
            sv = repr(v)
            ref = mappings.get(sv)
            if ref is not None:
                d[k] = ref
            else:
                mappings[sv] = v
                optmap(d[k], mappings)     
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, item in d:
            sitem = repr(item)
            ref = mappings.get(sitem)
            if ref is not None:
                d[idx] = sitem
            else:
                mappings[sitem] = item
                optmap(item, mappings)


data = json.load(in_file.open())
optmap(data)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.serializer.ANCHOR_TEMPLATE = u'%d'
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
en:
  models: &1
    errors:
      name: name not found
      url: bad url
  user: *1
  photo: *1
```

The above will also make references to, and traverse, arrays in your JSON.

As you can see your output can be further "compressed" than you though it could be.

---

I am not fluent enough in JavaScript to have written this answer in that language (without investing too much effort and delivering some ugly code), but the OP obviously understood the intent of `optmap()` and implemented it in [his answer](https://www.test.de/Die-Billigen-maehen-nicht-gut-4517665-0/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Python script from [Anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307905/anthon) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55808583/10103951

```
function buildRefsJson(inputJson, mappings = null) {
if (!mappings) {
    mappings = {}
}
if (typeof(inputJson) === 'object') {
    let value
    let stringValue
    let ref
    for (let key in inputJson) {
        value = inputJson[key]
        stringValue = JSON.stringify(value)
        ref = mappings[stringValue]
        if (ref) {
            inputJson[key] = ref
        } else {
            mappings[stringValue] = value
            buildRefsJson(inputJson[key], mappings)
        }
    }
}
```

I transformed it to JavaScript code. And it did the work! Also thanks to [Niroj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039490/niroj-shrestha) for helping

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's no solution to convert JSON to YML with references as far as I know, cause there's no such 'references' rule for repeating nodes in JSON. As the [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963) says, YAML can therefore be viewed as a natural **superset** of JSON.